# Rails log sorting by request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

In any medium/high concurrence Rails production environment you usually see the logs are messed up between requests. That means that any amount of consecutive log lines are not corresponding to the same request but to several ones.

Any trick, gem, unix tool to take a Rails.log file and sort it up so all **the same request log lines will be shown in consecutive order?**

I'm not looking for the Rails.log file to be sorted in real time, I want to sort an already closed Rails.log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [log_runes](https://github.com/wlipa/log_runes) gem for this.  It uses the Rails tagged logger to put a compact signature of the session id and request id on each log line so that it's easy to extract the log output for a session or a request with grep.